# Submitting a form works but no message shows

Tags: php, laravel, macos, forms, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to create a website. I linked the database to a form, and it works. When I submit the form, the only problem is that it shows me a black screen and that it's downloading. I can get the data saved in the database, but no message shows, and this block isn't okay at all.

I guess it is a front-end problem. Does anyone have any idea?

Code for form in Blade:

```
<section id="share-story" class="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>Stories</h2>
      <p>Share Your Story with Us</p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 mt-lg-0">

        <form action="{{route('share-story')}}" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
          @csrf
          
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 5 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="story" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please Share Something" placeholder="Your Story"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
            <div class="sent-message"> Your post has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit"> Send Story </button></div>
        </form>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

**PostController**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $response = Posts::create($request->all());

    if ($response) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->with(['msg' => 'post has been added', 'status' => 201]);
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->with(['msg' => 'an issue occured', 'status' => 201]);
    }
}
```

This is [how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGeoU.png) when I submit even though I get the data in the database.

Comment: share code can find the problem. please share the related part of codes

Comment: You really need to post some code and give a bit of an example.  At least like what you are posting, how your are posting (i.e. AJAX vs. not), the route, the controller, and what you are returning, if anything via JSON for AJAX, any error messages, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check if `return back()` is working instead of `return redirect()->back()`

Comment: Post the Javascript, AJAX, or JQuery codes that you used for your alert message.

Answer (score 0):

Some time back isn't work, because you already submit the form, now you don't have access on previous route.
Other time there is no back route on browser history on that particular tab(For JavaScript based websites) or server session(for server rendered website), as you can directly access the particular route.

So I always recommended to avoid `return redirect()->back();` instead use particular route where you want to back. Such as `return redirect()->route('hello');`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if ($response) {
    return redirect()->route('')->with(['msg' => 'Post has been added', 'status' => 201]);
} else {
    return redirect()->route('')->with(['msg' => 'An error occured', 'status' => 201]);
}
```

Define your route inside your route function.